# Особенности использования блока try в конструкторе класса

Tags: java

Вопрос из корпоративного теста при приеме на стажировку. Что на него можно ответить?

Comment: Этот вопрос нужо было задать на месте, им самим, и послушать что тебе ответят.

Comment: Это было не совсем уместно.
  - Было достаточно много народу.
  - Вопрос после теста уменьшил бы мои шансы.

Comment: А на какую позицию и в какую компанию если не секрет?

Comment: Инфосистемы Jet.
Стажировка.Было 67 человек,прошло примерно 20,я не в их числе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исключения в конструкторе это вообще не очень желательны. При выкидывании исключения из конструктора объект будет "полусоздан" и при первой же возможности будет вычищен сборщиком мусора, при этом еще возникнет проблема уязвимости кода, т.н. [атака по файналайзеру](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html).

Надо стараться использовать lazy-init, с инициализацией переменных которые уж точно не будут выкидывать исключения. Или же надо пользоваться каким-нить типа Factory/Фабрика навроде:

```
MyClass myObject=MyFactory.createMyClassObject();
```

в этом случае можно спокойно обработать `try-catch` и выкинуть типизированное исключение либо `null`

Но возвращаясь к вопросу кто же делать с try-catch в конструкторе если все таки будет исключение. Ответ будет такой:

1. Перегрузить метод `finalize();` в котором подчистить за собой все хвосты
2. В блоке catch() вызвать `System.runFinalization()` - который и вызовет все финализаторы объектов
3. Ну еще может быть добить вызовом сборщика мусора - правда, не уверен...

Comment: Вызовом System.runFinalization() мы вызовем не только его метод финализации,но и всех других обьектов в программе? Если да, то не попортит ли это обьекты, ведь многие из них еще нужны. Может быть вопрос немного некорректный, но все же

Comment: не попортит, под коллектор попадают только ненуждые объекты. Да и, имхо, не надо замарачиватся с чисткой, предположим у нас память 100%, программа юзает 95%, у вас есть ЦЕЛЫХ 5% запаса, даже если мусора наберется на 4%, останется 1% запаса, и сработает gc, который даже не узнает, что был близок OOM. Возможно, это привычка осталась у прогеров олдскула с Спп, но на ваши лабораторные работы эти проблемы недолжны распространятся ))

Comment: У меня нет лаб по Java, но за разьяснение спасибо.Очень подробное изложение)

Comment: а какие вариаеты ответа были, если это тест? может они хотели услышать, что если в конструкторе инициализируется какой то поток для чтерия файла, его надо будет екраниповать try?

Comment: Я назвал это тестированием, но оно лишь отчасти им являлось, на большинство вопросов не было вариантов. Вообще тест очень понравился даже в том плане, что нашел пробелы в знаниях, которые не показывали тесты в онлайне. До сих пор не знаю, почему не прошел, из-за курса(они хотели 4-5, а я 3ий) или из-за уровня знаний.

Comment: Вопрос на мой взгляд не самый простой:)

Comment: тесты, сам недавно завалил одни, это не показатель знаний, был вопрос по джава скрипту - в какой переменной хранится производитель браузера? или вопросы на внимательность, назвали метод и переменную одним именем и спрошивают, что в консоль упадет...  ))